# Generic absoluteness

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic

In Theorem 14 of "On The Question Of Absolute Undecidability" Peter Koellner describes a generic absoluteness result which could be summed up as $\Sigma^2_1(\Gamma^\infty)$-generic absoluteness, $\Gamma^\infty$ being the collection of universally Baire sets, and attributes it to Woodin. I was just wondering if anyone can tell me a place in the literature where a proof appears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is in Steel's paper "[The Derived Model Theorem](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Esteel/papers/dm.pdf)," Section 5.